# Firefox and Jpictura - .jpictura() scrolling to top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm using jpictura to format pictures in my HTML. When I re-invoke the .jpictura() function when I add more images, it scrolls to the top of the page. I've only noticed this problem while using Firefox. Why is it scrolling to the top of the page? How can I make it so that the window doesn't change position (scroll to the top) when new pictures are formatted?

I've tried this so far but it doesn't work. I call this function to format new images on the page, and theoretically it should scroll the window to the position where the user was before the new images were loaded, and not scroll to the top of the page. This problem is only happening in Firefox.

```
    function formatImages() {
        var currentPosition = $('html').offset().top;
        $("#imageResults").jpictura(); // Formats the images
        window.scrollTo(currentPosition);
    }
```